# Derivative Integral Problem

Tags: calculus, integration

Preface: I am sorry if there is a blatently obvious error or problem with my logic, I am only just learning about the fundamental theorem of Calculus and have been stumped by this example problem and why it has the solution that it does.

I will first show my understanding and what I originally thought was the solution, the problem is:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int _{a}^{f(x)} g(t)dt = ?$$
My solution:
$$ \text{let } h(x) = \int_{a}^{f(x)}  g(t)dt$$
By the chain rule:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}h(f(x) = h'(f(x)\cdot{}f'(x)$$
$$ h'(x) = d/df \int_a^{f(x)}g(t)dt $$
By the fundamental theorem of Calculus, the derivative and the integral should cancel correct?
$$\frac{d}{df} \int_a^{f(x)}g(t)dt = g(t) $$
Therefore:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int _{a}^{f(x)} g(t)dt = g(t)\cdot{}f'(x)$$

This however is not the correct answer, I have been told it is really this:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int _{a}^{f(x)} g(t)dt = g(f(x))\cdot{}f'(x)$$

Again, I apologize if there is some obvious error, Any and all help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: "$t$" isn't a proper variable here, just a dummy variable for the integral.  It can not appear in the final result.

Comment: Your only real mistake was in not realizing that $t$ is a dummy variable that has meaning inside the integral, but can **not** have meaning in the computation of the derivative.

Comment: Your definition of $h(x)$ is wrong. The way you define it then $h(f(x))$ would be $\int_{a}^{f(f(x))}  g(t)dt$, not $\int_{a}^{f(x)}  g(t)dt$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the comments, my idea of the fundamental theorem of calculus was flawed, I have realized I wrote a few things down wrong which carried out through my work, I will fix this now and post this answer to resolve the question. (I can only resolve my own answer in 2 days unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

okay lets define:
$$G(x)=\int_0^xg(t)dt$$
so the integral you have can be defined as:
$$\frac d{dx}\left[G(f(x))-G(a)\right]$$
Obviously if we take the derivative of a constant this disappears, so we just care about the first part:
$$\frac{d}{dx}G(f(x))=\frac{dG(f)}{df}\frac{df(x)}{dx}=G'(f(x))f'(x)$$
Now notice that by FTC:
$$G'(x)=g(x)$$
and so:
$$G'(f(x))f'(x)=g(f(x))f'(x)$$
so you got the correct result in the end there were just some steps to justify which were wrong